# How to test Kong API using postman?

Tags: php, curl, kong, api-gateway

I'm new in api-gateway technology and right now I'm starting to learn about it for my next project, especially Kong API Gateway. I already read the documentation but I'm still confused about how to test the API using postman. There is a way to test kong using `curl` like this:

```
$ curl -i -X GET \
  --url http://localhost:8000/ \
  --header 'Host: example.com'
```

Why do we still need to pass `localhost:8000` instead of just `example.com`? How to use it with postman? What does `header` mean in this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Postman is GUI application for making REST calls. Just enter the URL, select HTTP call type (Get/Post/any other), add headers if any and click on send to get the response.

If you have installed the kong on the same machine/system from which you are making call, then in url localhost will be used, otherwise DNS or IP of the machine on which kong is installed with port.

If you are not sure about headers, better to go with any beginner's guide for HTTP and REST. In simple terms headers, its just some meta data you send along when you make a HTTP request.

Comment: thanks for your answer, so from your explanation let say my dns name sample.com, and i add my internal api into kong api with host name api.sample.com so when i want to try accessing via mobile apps is it correct the url like this https://sample.com:8000 with header host api.sampel.com?